# .htaccess rewrite to simultaneously change domain and remove path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

My URL structure is currently as follows:

http://domain.com/folder/filename (CURRENT)

I want to change this so that I can use the following URL instead:

http://sub.domain.com/filename (NEW)

So accessing the CURRENT **or** the NEW url, should load the file located at the CURRENT url, but show the NEW url in the address bar. It should only apply to the "/folder/" path.

sub.domain.com is a mirror of domain.com, ie. they share the same file system and root directory.

This is what I have so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is working, but is missing the rule to remove the "/folder/" from the path. I've tried combining multiple RewriteRule's with no luck.  Any ideas? Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:** Thanks again @Gerben - I understand what your rules are doing now, but the second one isn't working for me. I suspect because it's conflicting with some other rewrite rules, in particular those of WordPress, which are lower down in my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Because of this the page ends up in a redirect loop, ie (from Chrome):
"The webpage at http://sub.domain.com/folder/index.php has resulted in too many redirects." - while the url I was originally trying to access was, for example, http://sub.domain.com/page

Any ideas?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Gerben - thanks, but like @jon-lin's answer below, this is also resulting in a 404, as the file doesn't physically exist at http://sub.domain.com/ - but I want it to appear that it does. If .htaccess rewriting is not the correct solution for this problem then I'm open to alternative ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(folder/)?(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect everything to sub.domain.com, and remove the `/folder` part of the URI *if it is there*. If not, it redirects and leaves the URI untouched.

Comment: Thanks @jon-lin. This is only partly working.

The redirect is working, ie. "http://domain.com/folder/filename" (CURRENT) redirects to "http://sub.domain.com/filename" (NEW).

But this results in a 404, since that file at the NEW url doesn't exist. The file at the CURRENT url hasn't moved.

It's more of a URL rewrite than a physical redirect that I need. Typing the NEW url in the browser should load the page at the CURRENT url, without changing the url in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /folder/
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1 [L]

# WordPress rules here
```

**edit** the second `R=301` should not have been there

But this won't work, as wordpress has no way of knowing you want `folder`. You could add the Proxy flag to the rewrite, but then you need to change the rule above to not redirect on this internal proxy request.

Comment: Thanks, I've replied below (couldn't include required formatting in a comment)

Comment: Yes `folder` is part of WP: a parent page.

Comment: Thanks, how would I go about that (change to rule to not redirect on the internal proxy) ? This is driving me insane so whatever works!

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help so far, appreciate it!